# Java - Is it possible to return value from inner class without creating new instance

Tags: java, class, inner-classes, static-classes

I'd like to create such structure, where user can go into inner classes, and receive a value even if he stopped on class itself.

Here's and example

```
public abstract class TREE {
    public static class PLAYER{
        private static final int value = 100; //(idea example)where to store inner PLAYER value
        public static final int NAME  = 0;
        public static final int SURNAME  = 1;
    } 
}
```

While its possible to go to value using

```
int a = TREE.PLAYER.NAME;
```

I'd like to also be able get value using

```
int b = TREE.PLAYER;
```

I would prefer not to use any functions, but simply going through path using dot operator. The value itself could be stored in class (like in my example under PLAYER class *value*) or simply returned in some other way, but i dont know if this is possible.

Maybe other structure im not aware of would be more suitable for such structure.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to initialize the player class with those values you have specified ? why not use a constructor ?

Comment: Also, that is not an inner class. It is a nested class which is static.

Comment: which value do you want to get as `TREE.PLAYER`?

Comment: Id like to get primitives byte, short and int from different nested static classes.

@DarthCoder Id like to pre define those values as constants, none of the values wont be changed at run time.

Comment: @Scavs I really don't get what you want. TREE.PLAYER is a class, it's a skeleton of how that PERSON class would be. If you want it to be a value then i am not sure what you are looking for. If you are looking at Enum then that is a very different story.

Comment: It doesn't matter really if its a class or enum, as long as value can be retrieved and more value can be accessed by going deeper with dot operator. Do you know if its possible using enums? Enums can hold only level of values, but Id like to create as much levels as i want. For example TREE.PLAYER.NAME.FIRST
I dont know if such dynamic structure is possible, that's why i ask (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Java you can't define the "default" value. In Java, when you have some syntactical construct you can expect it to behave consistently. Unfortunately, this also prevent you from creating "magic".

Back to your case, the closest thing to having "default" value would be create the function with the same name as your class. In this case you will be able to access "default" value by adding empty parentheses to your "class name":

```
public class TREE {

    public static int PLAYER() {
        return PLAYER.VALUE;
    }

    public final static class PLAYER {
        private PLAYER() {
        }

        public final static int VALUE = 1;
        public final static String NAME = "Player";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TREE.PLAYER());
        System.out.println(TREE.PLAYER.NAME);
    }
}
```

Another option will be to use short identifiers that are legal in Java, like `$` or `_`:

```
public final static class PLAYER {
    private PLAYER() {
    }

    public final static int _ = 1;
    public final static int $ = 1;
    public final static int VALUE = 1;
    public final static String NAME = "Player";
}
```

So you can access "default value" like this: `TREE.PLAYER.$`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, i guess using functions is my only bet here.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, much appreciate

Answer (score 2):

`TREE.PLAYER` is a type so you can only do something like

```
Class b = TREE.PLAYER.class;
```

If you want to get a value like an `int` you need to refer to a public field which can be cast to an int.

Java doesn't support adding syntactic sugar to pretend a class is a int field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i still wonder how java.lang primitive wrappers managed to be returned and assigned to values.

Integer a = 5;
int b = a;

Cant same be created for non instance classes?

Comment: @Scavs this is called [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and it's supported on language level only for predefined value types. It's impossible to create your own boxed type.